# How to cascade windows vertically or horizontally in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, window-manager

How can I cascade windows vertically or horizontally in Windows 7?

In Windows XP, I'm used to pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, selecting some windows, right-clicking them and then choosing "Cascade".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you mean "Tile vertically or horizontally"?

You can use [Aero Snap](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/03/17/designing-aero-snap.aspx): move 1 window on the left side of the screen and the other windows on the right side of the screen. Both will maximize to half the size of the screen, making it easy to view both at the same time.

Comment: Not so useful with more than just 2 windows.

Comment: yeah that's right and you know what ? you can also press Windows-key + LEFT or RIGHT to arrange them(need more time to familiarize with win7), and congratulation for your 1000 rep point :) thx

Comment: Thanks! 1024 now, perfect number for a computer guy! ;-)

Answer (score 12):

Right click on the Taskbar:
Stack windows = vertical
Show windows side by side = horizontal

Comment: I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

To cascade or tile only a specific group (say several Excel windows open at the same time), hit the shift key first then right click and select the cascade or tile option you want. Note, this assumes the individual windows are being combined; that is an optional property for the task bar.

Answer (score 0):

From Windows 7 site - [Working with windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Working-with-windows)

To choose one of these options, right-click an empty area of the taskbar, then click Cascade Windows, Show Windows Stacked, or Show Windows Side by Side.

Comment: Thanks for the link, shame there's no keyboard shortcut to save using the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where to put this since I don't have 50 reputation yet to comment. Eran has the most straightforward answer.

Right click on the Taskbar:
Cascade windows = vertical
Show windows side by side = horizontal

@wonea brought up a good point that there is no keyboard shortcut to cause Windows to cascade windows currently, and this means that you can't bind it to a mouse shortcut.

This is pretty inconvenient, maybe a future feature should make a windows shortcut for it like "Win + C"