# How to tile or cascade windows of an individual program?

Tags: windows-7, windows, window-manager

A [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/39913/cascading-windows-vertically-or-horizontally), while it tells you how to tile or cascade, does not tell you how to tile or cascade the windows of an individual program in Windows 7, as you could do in Windows XP. Does anyone know the answer to this question? When I'm sorting through my unsaved Notepad windows, I have no wish to share the screen space with 50 Chrome windows, you can't see a thing.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way that you can tile ONLY the windows of a specific program.  You may be out of luck.

Comment: Well, I could roll back to Windows XP ;)

Comment: Another note - after actually trying the reduced Windows 7 function, I find that it doesn't cascade or tile everything, just everything that's currently not minimized.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For grouped icons
set (right click on taskbar --> Properties --> "Taskbar buttons" to "Always combine, hide labels")
you can hold down shift and right click on the group.

This reveals the menu items 'Show windows stacked' and 'Show windows side-by-side'

Comment: Nice... It offers 'Cascade' as well. :)

Comment: Excellent, you are godlike.  I should always try things with shift, it seemed like they'd changed their philosophy to less power-user-friendly so I was afraid it was just gone. Too bad they changed the names from horizontal/vertical less intuitive but we'll get used to it.

Comment: I don't have these menu items showing up .. I'm on windows 10 though. How do we do it on windows 10?

Comment: aha I figured it out - [How to tile/cascade/... all windows of a certain program?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ab1aa358-86b1-4341-811c-71b96566fdc6/how-to-tilecascade-all-windows-of-a-certain-program?forum=w7itproui) , just in case anyone was interested - sneaky microsoft

Comment: 2021, Win 10: The solution is to hold the shift key while right-clicking the taskbar button. Silly decision.